# How to replicate this? "\n" is being used?

Tags: php

I am trying to replicate this using PHP:

```
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0\n2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
```

Although when I am doing so:

```
$hello = date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n" . date("Y-m-d", $one) . ";0;0;0;0\n";
```

the "\n" is being used and placing the data on a new line each time, for example, it is being output as such:

```
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
2011-03-30;0;0;0;0
```

How can I stop this and replicate what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the backslash - so you have `\\n` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 6):

Using single quotes instead of double quotes.  Single quotes are string literals so ignore special characters like `\n`.

Answer (score 5):

Either use single quotes (like Nick proposed) or escape the backslash by another backslash, so write:

```
  ";0;0;0;0\\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes OR escape the escape character `\\n`

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes. In this case you don't even need the double quote functionality.

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php